# Difference Between HSDPA and HSUPA USB Modem

Tags: c#, wireless, gsm

I have two **`GSM Modems`**.

- **HSDPA** (High-Speed Downlink Packet Access)
- **HSUPA** (High-Speed Unlink Packet Access)

I want to send `SMS` from my `C# Application` using these devices. I have used `GSMCommServer,GSMCommShared,GSMCommunication and PDUConverter dlls`. 
Here is my Code.

```
   SmsSubmitPdu p;
   String message = txtMessage.Text;
   string contactNo = txtContactNo.Text;
   if (comm.IsConnected() == true)
   {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        byte dcs = (byte)DataCodingScheme.GeneralCoding.Alpha7BitDefault;
        p= new SmsSubmitPdu(message, contactNo, dcs);
        comm.SendMessage(p);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

This code works fine with `HSDPA`, while using `HSUPA`, it gives me an error `Modem is not responding`.

What is the difference between `HSDPA` and `HSUPA`, that the above code works for `HSDPA` and not working for `HSUPA`. The error is thrown on `comm.SendMessage(p);` Statement, which means the modem is connected.

Answer (score 0):

HSDPA and HSUPA are the next generation for GPRS modems to increase the available bandwidth for an Internet connection and there are modems out there that combine both which will then be called HSPA modems (and to increase the bandwidth even more you could take LTE). But these packet oriented connections won't be used for SMS.

To send an SMS your modem must be configured with a phone number of the SMS central where it should send the message (this is provider specific) which will then send a message (NOT the SMS) to the desired receiver which will then connect to the provider central (even if it is a different provider then the receivers provider) to receive this message.

So you should take a look into the manual of your modem to find out how to configure the SMS central and also ask the provider of your SIM card for these informations.